# What does btrfs do if a disk in my RAID10 dies?

Tags: btrfs, monitoring

I've just moved from mdadm to "native" btrfs. Under mdadm I could set my email in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` and if it had any issues with a disk, it would fire emails at me on boot. This has saved my bacon at least once.

Being new to btrfs, I want to make sure that I'm afforded the same protection. I want some sort of notification if a disk dies or won't come up at boot or resume.

What's available?